# UITableViewController is not scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableViewController that will not scroll. After researching online I found that the table view is a subclass of the scroll view and that it will allow scrolling after 10 items are in the list.

However, I have custom cells that very large (~300px) so with just two it already goes beyond the screen. How can I get the table view to scroll with less than 10 items since my cells are so large.

Comment: Make sure you have scrolling enabled, check the attribute inspector in storyboard, make sure the Scrolling Enabled box is checked.

Comment: Yes scrolling is enabled. Does it matter if I used a View Controller with a Table View inside of it versus using a Table View Controller?

Comment: No, using a `UIViewController` is actually what I always use. Just make sure you assign the delegate and datasource and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh ok, yup those are set. Also, the data is showing up fine but it just wont let me scroll with just the two cells. Am doing this on an iPod touch 5th Gen by the way

Comment: it should work then, as long as the `tableView` has content to scroll. as s test, make your `tableView` smaller than the screen, maybe one table cell high. If you have two cells, it should scroll.

Comment: It should just work. This, "I found that the table view is a subclass of the scroll view and that it will allow scrolling after 10 items are in the list" is wrong. Whether it scrolls has nothing to do with the number of rows, it should scroll if all the cells you have, no matter how many that is, won't fit on screen at one time.

Comment: Is bounce enabled? You can scroll without more than 1 item in the tableView...

Comment: What subviews do you have in your cell? If you have a large image view, for instance, the cell won't receive your touch unless you set its userInteractionEnabled property to YES.

Comment: The cells do have a UIImageView which takes majority of the cell size. Bounce is enabled, I have it enabled in the storyboard as well as in the view controller. What should be set in the size inspector. I am wondering if some settings in here got messed up

Comment: @ajk4550: There is no limits like you need to have 10 cells on tableview. Because UITableView is scroll enabled to true by default. Check your table view or any of the superview of tableview has userInteractionEnabled to false.