# When UITableViewController is a child of UITabBarController, scrolling does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I created 4 different `UITableViewControllers`, wrapped them into the respective 4 `UINavigationControllers` and added all of them to `UITabBarViewController`, like this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navIVC, navLVC, navFVC, navSVC];
```

in `AppDelegate.m`

Then, in a `UITableViewController` scrolling is not working, the image is below.[image]

So, I can not for some reason scroll further down; there is still a plenty of cells below. How could I make it scrolling? I tried enabling scrolling like this: `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;`, but it does not work. The problem is similar to the following unanswered one: [UITableViewController is not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803032/uitableviewcontroller-is-not-scrolling)

Comment: why aren't you adding the tabs to the tabbar in storyboard?

Comment: I am not using storyboard. I have `.xib` that represents the cells: `[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"EVTItemCell"]`, and the images for the tab bar are added in the respective `UITableViewControllers`: `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
        self.tabBarItem.image = image;
`. I am not sure what you mean, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question. The problem is that I am very new to Xcode and its infrastructure. So, when the simulator launches it shows me scrollbar that is actually appearing just because I have small screen size of my laptop and it is just for viewing the simulator's screen. The scrollbar was misleading for me. The only thing that I needed to do is to click and then scroll. In other words, everything is (and was) working perfectly.